# Laravel store method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to make store eloquent to be more simplified to something like this:

```
$keyword = Keyword::create([
        'keyword'       => $request->input('keyword'),
        'micro_price'   => $request->input('micro_price'),
        'macro_price'   => $request->input('macro_price'),
        'cmd'           => $request->input('cmd'),
]);
```

Instead of this:

```
    $keyword = new Keyword;
    $keyword->keyword = $request->input('keyword');
    $keyword->micro_price = $request->input('micro_price');
    $keyword->macro_price = $request->input('macro_price');
    $keyword->cmd = $request->input('cmd');
    $keyword->user()->associate(Auth::user());
    $keyword->server()->associate($request->input('title'));
    $keyword->save();
```

But there is a problem that I have in **keywords** database table with 2 foreign keys (`server_id` and `user_id`) and I want that my eloquent model assign these 2 foreign keys properly, but I have no idea how to make that in simplified version.

Thanks in advance for help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment) feature and `all()` request method:

```
$keyword = Keyword::create($request->all());
```

It'll work if you'll define `$fillable` property in the `Keyword` model:

```
protected $fillable = ['keyword', 'cmd', 'micro_price', 'mini_price'];
```

If you need to associate a keyword with two models, you can define foreign keys manually:

```
$data = $request->all();
$data['user_id'] = auth()->id();
$data['server_id'] => $request->title;
$keyword = Keyword::create($data);
```

To associate an object with one model you can use relationship:

```
auth()->user()->keywords()->create($request->all());
```

Comment: Thanks. Maybe there is a chance to associate more than 1 model? For example Server and User model in one line?

Comment: @Sprunkas if one line solution is really that important, use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to merge array returned by `$request->all()` and array with foreign keys.